# ApiRTC: Is there a way to get a call duration, or hang up call at specific duration or time?

Tags: javascript, laravel, webrtc, real-time, real-time-clock

I am working on a project that includes real-time communication through ApiRTC?

Looking for a solution to destroy call at specific duration, or at specific time, for example at 6PM?

Is there any way to get call duration and based on that destroy (hang up) a call?

Answer (score 0):

This can be managed in your application by starting a timer when you start the call

Comment: It is very obvious.